# Using a while loop to create a pyramid in C#

Tags: c#, for-loop, while-loop

I'm learning here some of C# still, but I have made a pyramid from asterisks with for loop:

```
using System;     

namespace Nimi{      
class Ohjelma{      
static void Main(){ 
for(;;){ 
Console.Write("Anna korkeus: ");     
string eka = Console.ReadLine();     
int luku = int.Parse(eka); 
//First, I made that if the number is 0 or lower, it will ask the number again. 
//Hence the endless loop at start.
if(luku <= 0){ 
    continue; 
} else { 
    for (int i = 0; i < luku; i++ ) 
    { 
                for (int k=i+1; k < luku; k++) 
                   { 
                        Console.Write(" "); 
                } 
                for (int j = 2*i+1; j > 0; j--) 
                { 
                        Console.Write("*"); 
                    } 
            Console.WriteLine(""); 
           } 
        break; 
    } 
} 
} 
} 
}
```

I'm just out of curiosity wanting to know how this would work with while-loop which I haven't been able to create still. The way I thought it would be:

```
using System;     

namespace Nimi{      
class Ohjelma{      
static void Main(){ 
while(true){ 
// The While-loop version of endless loop. Not sure how different it is.
Console.Write("Anna korkeus: ");     
string eka = Console.ReadLine();     
int luku = int.Parse(eka); 
if(luku <= 0){ 
    continue; 
} else {
    int i = 0;
    int j = i * 2 + 1;
    int k = i+1;
    while(i < luku)
    {
        while (j > 0){
            while (k < luku){
            Console.Write(" ");
            k++;
            }
        Console.Write("*");
        j--;
        }
    Console.WriteLine();
    i++;
    }
    break;
    }
} 
} 
} 
}
```

Don't really work out. It only posts something like this (when value is 4:

```
   *
```

What's the correct way to transfer from for-loop to while-loop to create a pyramid with asterisks?

Comment: Just to be clear, what's the expected output?

Comment: your typical for loop is the equivalent of `int = 0;while(i < something){i++;}`

Comment: p.s.w.g: A pyramid of asterisk. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/BlogImages/10162012053909AM/Asterisk-Paramid-in-csharp.jpg Much like this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
using System;

namespace Nimi
{
    class Ohjelma
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            for (; ; )
            {
                Console.Write("Anna korkeus: ");
                string eka = Console.ReadLine();
                int luku = int.Parse(eka);
                //First, I made that if the number is 0 or lower, it will ask the number again. 
                //Hence the endless loop at start.
                if (luku <= 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    int i = 0;

                    while (i < luku)
                    {
                        int k = i + 1;

                        while (k < luku)
                        {
                            Console.Write(" ");
                            k++;
                        }

                        int j = 2 * i + 1;

                        while (j > 0)
                        {
                            Console.Write("*");
                            j--;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("");

                        i++;
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And remember: if your code is correctly formatted, it's easier to read. ^ED in Visual Studio to format everything.**

(^ED means CTRL+E and then D (with the D you don't need the CTRL, it will work both ways)

Comment: That definitely helps :) And actually no, I'm not using Visual Studio for this. It's a site pretty much. Oh yeah though. You had for(;;) at the start still. changing that to while(true) and no problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
            for (int j = 2*i+1; j > 0; j--) 
            { 
                    Console.Write("*"); 
                }
```

becomes

```
{
    int j = 2*i+1;
    while (j > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("*");

        j--;
    }
}
```

Note that the "extra" curly braces preserve the locality of `j`, just like the `for()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     private static void pyramid()
    {
         int k = 10;
        int j=0;
        while(true)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                if (i >= (k - j) && i <= (k + j))
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                    Console.Write("\t");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\t");
                }
                if (i > (j + k))
                {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
            if (j == (k - 1))
            {
                break;
            }

                j++;
        }

    }
```